# ViewVC Showing viewvc.cgi file content instead of SVN repositories

Tags: svn, viewvc

Using Ubuntu 18.04

SVN & ViewVC configuration

```
<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn
   SVNListParentPath On
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion Repository"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn.passwd
   Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /viewvc>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "ViewSVN"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn.passwd
   #AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
   Require valid-user
</Location>
#ScriptAlias /viewvc /usr/lib/cgi-bin/viewvc.wsgi
ScriptAlias /viewvc /usr/lib/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi
```

Also added svn_roots in the viewvc.conf

SVN is working and showing all repositories in browser, but ViewVC show viewvc.cgi file content instead of repositories.

Answer (score 0):

See [the faq](https://viewvc.org/faq.html):

> The trick appears to be the presence of the **trailing slash** character on the ScriptAlias directive.

Replace

```
ScriptAlias /viewvc /usr/lib/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi
```

with

```
ScriptAlias /viewvc /usr/lib/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @navylover, but it's not working